# What is the best and fastest way to liquify Nutella chocolate spread?

Tags: chocolate, melting-chocolate

I usually put some amount in a cup and add a very small amount of water to start mixing. This is usually effective as long as the amount of water is very small compared to chocolate, in which the chocolate still has a strong taste.
I thought of using milk, but I do not want the chocolate's taste to be faded (milk has a taste compared to water being neutral ).I also tried using the microwave, but that was pretty useless.

I want something really fast and reliable.

Comment: @DMz- what consistency are you trying to achieve?

Comment: And what are you actually trying to do with it? Heating it in a microwave does melt it, but apparently that's useless?

Comment: Im just a student trying to put some melted chocolate on bananas ..

Comment: @Jefromi - I wasn't going there. lol!

Comment: @DMz - If there's a way to thin Nutella, we'll find it!

Comment: Haha im not a cook, nor do I have cooking skills. But as a student I try to do something from time to time. Plus I don't have that many cooking ingredients (hence why I just use water + nutella).

Comment: For future questions, you'll probably get better answers if you explain what you're doing (and what you've tried) in the first place - in particular, nutella definitely melts when heated (it shouldn't solidify), and knowing that you want to put it over bananas is helpful.

Comment: Place inside car on a hot summer's day.

Comment: Please do not edit your answer into the question. If you have your own (different) solution then post it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Heating it up in the microwave will temporarily make it runnier, but then it will go back to its original consistency. Here are some ways that may work for you:

- Add some neutral flavored oil: just a bit though or it will get greasy
- Add chocolate syrup: chocolate syrup is very runny will thin it out while still keeping the chocolate flavor. Hershey's is available in the US and UK, Tate and Lyle makes one in the UK. Not sure where you are but there will likely be something available
- If you can't find chocolate syrup try making a very thick chocolate milk with some cocoa powder or chocolate milk powder

Comment: When I heated Nutella chocolate spread, it became very solid !! Well I do not have current access to chocolate syrup nor cocoa power. But I do have chocolate milk powder. So I mix that with a bit of water as well ?

Comment: @DMz, add it to milk, even if it says water, that will make it richer

Comment: @DMz: if it became solid you probably heated it too much!

Answer (score 4):

After experimentation, here is what we came up with:

- 1 tsp. of milk (I know you said no milk, but you need the fat in it
  to keep the Nutella from seizing)
- 1 TBSP. Nutella

**Instructions:**

- Heat the tsp. of milk a couple of seconds in a bowl in the microwave - just a couple seconds!!
- Take a little chunk from the TBSP. of Nutella and stir it into the milk until smooth
- Repeat the above step until it is the desired consistency for drizzling over your bananas - or whatever.  When it cools, it will be firm again.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Use a bain marie: get a pot of steaming hot water, and place a glass bowl on top.  Make sure the water isn't touching the glass bowl directly.  Place your chocolate in the bowl and stir and it will melt.

Answer (score 1):

I microwave a tsp of coconut oil for 15 seconds, then mix in a tbsp of Nutella and microwave in 10 second bursts until I'm happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

We place container of Nutella in a bowl of hot water...works faster if you put the amount you want in a small glass bowl and set it into a larger container of hot water. Melts but doesn't harden. Dip your banana right in. Easy!

Answer (score 1):

I found that adding any nut milk or regular milk made the Nutella thicker to a fudge like texture.

What worked for me was putting the Nutella in a glass bowl over a boiling pot of water (double boiler) and adding hot water teaspoon by teaspoon while mixing to the right consistency.

Answer (score 1):

Water works just fine. Add a little bit at a time and stir until combined if you want it thinner, add more water.

Answer (score 0):

1 Table spoon of Milk and 1 Table spoon sour cream to a half a jar (13 oz) of Nutella. It will not weaken the chocolate flavor, it actually enhances the flavor. Delicious!

Answer (score 0):

This method works! If you need to reduce the viscosity of nutella (make it more liquid/runny) here is what you do:

1. it must be fresh (expired/old nutella's chemical properties change)
2. 1 part nutella to 1/10 (10%) part whole milk - stir (it may become hard at first! don't stress)
3. once the first 10% is mixed in, add another 10% milk and again and again until its you reach the viscosity required.

The two secrets to thinning syrup and nutella are

- start with the syrup or nutella and SLOWLY add the milk/water
- ALWAYS add TINY/MINUTE/SMALL amounts [in ratio obviously. for a bucket containing 10Litres Nutella, you'll need 1 litre of milk ;) ]

Answer (score -1):

What i did for pancake day last year was get a pan of water and put a bowl over it, boil the water for a bit and then add the nuttella. gradually, add the milk bit by bit until it goes to the liquid thickness that you like. It worked for me so try it

Answer (score -1):

I used 1 teaspoon half and half to 1 tablespoon of Nutella.  Put half and half in small bowl in microwave until hot and then stirred in the Nutella.  Worked beautufully!  Was able to drizzle over my mini bunt cakes without losing any flavor. Tried many different ways before and ruined the Nutella.